# Ant build failed - build.xml

Tags: java, web-services, tomcat, ant

I'm trying to create a war file with Ant, but it just fails. As Ant is correctly set up, i guess the build.xml file is the problem.

Here is cmd messages :

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 9.0\webapps\prediction>
ant -Dwar.name=hi deploy
Buildfile: C:\Program Files (x86)\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 9.0\webapps\
prediction\build.xml

clean:

prepare:

BUILD FAILED
C:\Program Files (x86)\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 9.0\webapps\prediction\
build.xml:129: Directory C:\Program Files (x86)\Apache Software Foundation\Tomca
t 9.0\webapps\prediction\build creation was not successful for an unknown reason


Total time: 0 seconds
```

Here is my build.xml file :

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1aU7fMYsNUFGgrWJaEPHcRMxuQUfY1LM3/view?usp=sharing

I think the problem could be located in the path below the #### Change for your system. #### comment, but everything seems good at first sight :/.

Comment: Please post the relevant, short, `build.xml`. Most people are not  going to run off clicking on a link to a drive. Furthermore, such links reduce the ability of future people to read this question, as the link will likely be made redundant.

Comment: I know, but i couldn't do another way because StackOverflow didn't let me post that much code for the amount of explanation.

Comment: If it is "too much code", then the first step is to reduce the file to the most simple example that illustrates the issue. The [concept of an MVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies equally to this file.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem, it was because Tomcat was installed as a Service on my computer, and not as a standard application.